# Increase Session Time Out in PHP website on SHARED HOSTING

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, shared-hosting, php-ini

I have already tried all the possible solutions from the Stack Overflow. But none of them are working.
I recently got to know about that in Shared Hosting we have a different way of doing that. If anyone could help me in detail about how to do it so that session stay active for at least 24 hours.

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);
```

This does not solve my problem before the session start call.

Comment: One way would be to call php file with ajax every XX minutes

Comment: @Ingus but how will it keep the user login details when user is not actually using the website

Comment: `not actually using the website` means his PC is of, tab closed etc? If that so then yeah my example will not work. .. But if user page is still open it should keep session.

Comment: set the session cookie lifetime but please show all the methods you have tried

Comment: if the user is active than there is no issue it only occurs when he is not active for certain amount of time. @Ingus

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I have tried this but it is not working.

Comment: @TabishTanseef i know but when he counts as inactive in this case when tab is still open?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the methods ( with their configuration ) that you have used

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius please see

Answer (score 1):

I m not sure if this solution is for you but i will post how i did.
I do logout my user after XX minutes but to keep live session i call file with ajax and reset the sessions. If my set time expire i destroy session. This of course will only work if page is still opened.

In header i set:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['afkTime'])){
    unset($_SESSION['afkTime']);
}
```

In `<head></head>` tags i check how log time user is inactive:

```
<script>
    var refreshSn = function ()
    {
        var time = 1200000; // 20 mins | 1min = 60000 miliseconds 
        setTimeout(
            function ()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'refresh_session.php',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) { refreshSn(); console.log(data); if(data=='AFK logout'){ location.reload(); } }
                });
            },
            time
        );
    };

    // Call in page
    refreshSn()
</script>
```

In `refresh_session.php` if AFK time is bigger than my set time and if so i logout:

```
<?
session_start();

    if(empty($_SESSION['afkTime'])){
        $_SESSION['afkTime'] = 1200000;
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $_SESSION['login_user']; //REWRITE SESSION TO KEEP IT
        $_SESSION['session_id'] = $_SESSION['session_id']; //REWRITE SESSION TO KEEP IT
        echo 'AFK started';
        die();
    }else{
    
        if(!empty($_SESSION['afkTime']) && $_SESSION['afkTime']>= 7200000){
            unset($_SESSION);
            session_destroy();
            echo 'AFK logout';
            die();
        }else{    
            $_SESSION['afkTime'] = $_SESSION['afkTime']+1200000;
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $_SESSION['login_user']; //REWRITE SESSION TO KEEP IT
            $_SESSION['session_id'] = $_SESSION['session_id']; //REWRITE SESSION TO KEEP IT
                   
            echo 'AFK '.$_SESSION['afkTime'];
            die();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check what the `session.save_path` is set to.

If that is just a global temp directory you share with all other users running their sites on this machine - then the garbage collection triggered by them, with their much lower settings, might wipe your session data files as well.

In that case, you should change this setting to use your own directory. (That directory should of course not be publicly available via HTTP.)

Comment: can you please tell me about it 
I know your suggestion will solve the problem
where should I put the new file and what should I write in that

Comment: This is a configuration setting that can be changed the same way, as the one you already did try to change.

Comment: This setting needs to be set the same across _all_ of your scripts that use sessions though - if you had another script running which uses a lower value (either explicitly, or implicitly by falling back on the default), then that one would control when session files can be cleaned up again. So it would be better to make this setting across the whole project, in the central PHP configuration. https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php